# Using AM_INIT_AUTOMAKE parameters and configure script command line parameters

Tags: linux, build, autoconf, automake

Is it possible to use both command line parameters to the configure script, ala:

> ../configure CXXFLAGS=-O0 -g -foo -bar -bat

while simultaneously keeping any options that are passed to AM_INIT_AUTOMAKE in the configure.ac file? e.g.:

> AM_INIT_AUTOMAKE([-Wall -Werror])

My desired result is that ALL of the above flags are passed along, e.g.:

> -O0 -g -foo -bar -bat -Wall -Werror

It appears that specifying CXXFLAGS on the command line either ingores or overwrites what is passed into AM_INIT_AUTOMAKE. If anyone knows of a way to do the union of the two sets, that would be extremely helpful. Thx!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `-W` warning categories [options](http://www.gnu.org/software/automake/manual/automake.html#List-of-Automake-options) have nothing to do with `C[XX]FLAGS`. These are command line arguments used when invoking automake.

Conversely, the `AM_INIT_AUTOMAKE` options like `-Wall` don't affect the compiler flags. It's just the decision to use these switch names that is resulting in the confusion. They have a similar meaning, e.g., `-Werror` will treat automake warnings as errors, but are totally unrelated.

In short, you have to pass `-Wall`, etc., in `C[XX]FLAGS` to influence the compiler. And add `-Wall` to `AM_INIT_AUTOMAKE` to enable all warning categories when automake is invoked.